# How do I handle image data returned from an ajax get request

Tags: ajax, image, return, put

I am trying to understand how to deal with the data returned from a Cross-Origin AJAX GET request. In this case it is supposed to return "an image". I am new to Ajax so I'm hoping there is a simple answer to this. I have to include the `data = { width: 300px }` in my GET request. Simply using the browser to display the image shows a 75px image. I am interacting with an API so this is the method they recommend to get a 300px version.

```
function Ajaxwrapper (MYurl, MYdata, errorHandler, callback, method) {
  $.ajax({
        url: MYurl,
        data: MYdata,
        type: method,
        success: callback,
        error: errorHandler,
        xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
  });
}


function getPreview (el) {

    var url = 'http://MYURL';

    var data = {
        book: {
            width: '300px'
        }
    };

    Ajaxwrapper(url, data, function(xhr){ console.log(xhr.status); }, function(data){

        // How the heck do I deal with the data
        var HTMLpreview = '<img src="' + data + '">';

        el.append(HTMLpreview);

    }, 'get');
}
```

THIS IS WHAT IS OUTPUTTED USING THE `IMG SRC="returned data"`:

```
+���+�\�E��{�%�ns�$��E�9�k;k�-� �fd��Y�}��e�K���w��f@X���"Q�G%�ͼ%�����D5����"��2�!'��tbF����[����A0���5�>����' +���������-9���|8e� $0�GD�ڃ�e"t:C�<�������?�Z� �=��>��?�Oo����}�����6�o����}����b�zMuUťR��ds`� ֞�z�J���s~?{w��9�ֳ��bܠ"g����ط(�ٙ���dv��:���c���ʮd��Y�}��h��X���r��4 ]5���r��,d�"=��$�q����e���e�I|:<*DP]K`.��M�s�p��G�"���V]��F�ãѠQ ���(P�� :�"" )+%�ߏ���b�T���o��n�1>s��v�l[�L������{32]X��۾�T�\�{�_9U̗V+#���-8+�
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

-David

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing so this may not be what you're looking for.

Your api should give you information on what type of data it is returning (content type). You can use that to decide what to do with the result.

It looks like you're getting a binary image file. You can create a dom image object and insert it into your page to be displayed

If you're using straight javascript without a wrapper library it may be something like this: http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: I should have posted sooner.. the solution was very simple and should have been in the API docs. I just added ?width:### at the end of my image url. Didn't even need to use the API suggested GET request. Thanks for youre help anyway.